# How do I query a firebase collection by the 'in' paramater with more than 10 values?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have this function, `getFollowingPieces()` , where I get posts with userIds that the logged in user follows. Although now I've found it won't work if they follow more than 10 people. The only solution I've seen tells people to use a get request for each userId, but that doesn't allow for pagination or proper order of data. (Notice I'm using an `after` value and an `orderBy`) I'd hate to have to move off firebase for this limitation but the `following users` is a big aspect of this app. Here's my function below:

```
export async function getFollowingPieces(userId, following, filter, after) {
  const order = filter === "Popular" ? "likeCount" : "dateCreated";
  const result = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("pieces")
    .where("userId", "in", following.slice(0, 10))
    .where("published", "==", true)
    .orderBy(order, "desc")
    .limit(10)
    .get();
  const last = result.docs[result.docs.length - 1];
  const userFollowedPieces = result.docs.map((piece) => ({
    ...piece.data(),
    docId: piece.id,
  }));

  const piecesWithUserDetails = await Promise.all(
    userFollowedPieces.map(async (piece) => {
      let userLikedPiece = false;
      let userBookmarkedPiece = false;
      if (piece.likes.includes(userId)) {
        userLikedPiece = true;
      }
      if (piece.bookmarks.includes(userId)) {
        userBookmarkedPiece = true;
      }
      const user = await getUserByUserId(piece.userId);
      const { username, picture, fullName } = user[0];
      return {
        username,
        picture,
        fullName,
        ...piece,
        userLikedPiece,
        userBookmarkedPiece,
      };
    })
  );
  return { piecesWithUserDetails, last };
}
```

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/oaduch/is_ther_a_workaround_for_the_firebase_query_in/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the way Cloud Firestore indexes work, these limits are in place to discourage inefficient querying. In your use case, there are two ways that come to mind that could perform the desired query.

In either case, you will see performance benefits in bandwidth and latency by executing them using a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Of the two approaches, I recommend the first, as it is guaranteed to return relevant results if they exist.

#### Approach 1: Chunked requests

In this approach, you split the `following` array into blocks of 10 authors, make requests for each block and zip the sorted results together.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Max. documents retrieved: | `(Math.ceil(AUTHOR_COUNT / 10) * 10)` documents |
| Pros: | - Works well for small number of followed authors - Uses index-based querying - Will return related documents regardless of age/popularity |
| Cons: | - Wasteful document requests with large followed authors size |

```
/**
 * An intermediate state of processing a `PieceData` object used for sorting.
 * @typedef PieceMetadata
 *
 * @property {String} docId - the piece's document ID
 * @property {QueryDataSnapshot} snapshot - the piece's document snapshot
 * @property {Number | undefined} likeCount - the piece's value for `likeCount`
 * @property {Number | undefined} dateCreated - the piece's value for `dateCreated`
 */

/**
 * Returns the `pageSize` most recent pieces (as `PieceMetadata`
 * objects) sorted according to the given `order` field for the
 * given array of `authors`.
 *
 * `authors` must have less than 10 entries or you must use
 * `_getPublishedPiecesByBatchOfAuthors()` instead.
 *
 * Optionally, `after` can be provided as a `DataSnapshot` or
 * appropriate value for `order` to support paginated results.
 */
function _getPublishedPiecesByAuthors(authors, order, pageSize, after = undefined) {
  const query = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("pieces")
    .where("userId", "in", authors)
    .where("published", "==", true)
    .orderBy(order, "desc")
    .limit(pageSize);

  const result = (typeof after !== "undefined" ? query.startAfter(after) : query)
    .get();

  const pieceMetadataArr = [];

  result.forEach((piece) => {
    pieceMetadataArr.push({
      docId: piece.id,             // document ID
      [filter]: piece.get(filter), // likeCount/dateCreated as appropriate
      snapshot: piece              // unprocessed snapshot
    });
  });

  return pieceMetadataArr;
}

/** splits array `arr` into chunks of max size `n` */
function chunkArr(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) throw new Error("n must be greater than 0");
  return Array
    .from({length: Math.ceil(arr.length/n)})
    .map((_, i) => arr.slice(n*i, n*(i+1)))
}

/**
 * Returns the `pageSize` most recent pieces (as `PieceMetadata`
 * objects) sorted according to the given `order` field for the
 * given array of `authors`.
 *
 * `authors` may have as many entries as desired.
 *
 * Optionally, `after` can be provided as a `DataSnapshot` or
 * appropriate value for `order` to support paginated results.
 */
async function _getPublishedPiecesByBatchOfAuthors(authors, order, pageSize, after = undefined) {
  return Promise.all(
    chunkArr(authors, 10)
      .map(authorsInChunk => _getPublishedPiecesByAuthors(authorsInChunk, order, pageSize, after))
  )
    .then(resultBatches => {
      return resultBatches.flat()
        .sort((a,b) => a[order] - b[order]) // works if dateCreated is numeric
        .slice(0, pageSize); // only return first X results
    })
}

export async function getFollowingPieces(userId, following, filter, after = undefined) {
  const order = filter === "Popular" ? "likeCount" : "dateCreated";

  const sortedPieceMetadata = await _getPublishedPiecesByBatchOfAuthors(following, order, 10, after);

  const userFollowedPieces = sortedPieceMetadata // "hydrate" the pieces from their snapshot object
    .map(({ docId, snapshot }) => ({
      ...snapshot.data(), 
      docId
    }));

  const lastSnapshot = sortedPieces.length > 0
    ? sortedPieces[sortedPieces.length-1].snapshot
    : undefined;
   
  const piecesWithUserDetails = await Promise.all(
    userFollowedPieces.map(/* ... */)
  );

  return { piecesWithUserDetails, lastSnapshot };
}
```

#### Approach 2: Iterate `/pieces`

In this variation, you search each document in `/pieces` that matches the base query, and pick out those that match the user's followed authors list.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Max. documents retrieved: | `maxSearchCount` documents |
| Pros: | - Works well for large number of **active/popular** followed authors |
| Cons: | - Wasteful document requests with small followed authors size - Wasteful document requests with inactive/unpopular authors - May hit query limit before getting desired number of documents for inactive/unpopular authors - Requires client-based/function-based filtering |

```
async function findFromQuery(query, predicate, count, pageSize, maxSearchCount, after = undefined) {
  if (!query || !("orderBy" in query))
    throw new TypeError("query must be a Firestore Query or CollectionReference");
  if (typeof predicate !== "function")
    throw new TypeError("predicate must be a function, was " + typeof predicate);
  if (typeof count !== "number")
    throw new TypeError("count must be a number, was " + typeof count);
  if (typeof pageSize !== "number")
    throw new TypeError("pageSize must be a number, was " + typeof pageSize);
  if (typeof maxSearchCount !== "number")
    throw new TypeError("maxSearchCount must be a number, was " + typeof maxSearchCount);

  const pageQuery = query.limit(pageSize);
  const baseQuery = after
    ? pageQuery.startAfter(after)
    : pageQuery;

  const docs = [];
  let searched = 0, lastSnapshot = undefined;
  while (docs.length < count && searched < maxSearchCount) {
    const querySnapshot = await (lastSnapshot
      ? pageQuery.startAfter(lastSnapshot).get()
      : baseQuery.get();

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      if (predicate(doc)) {
        docs.push(doc);
      }
      lastSnapshot = doc;
    });

    searched += querySnapshot.size();
  }

  // may have more than `count` results, so only return that many
  return docs.slice(0, count);
}

export async function getFollowingPieces(userId, following, filter, after = undefined) {
  const order = filter === "Popular" ? "likeCount" : "dateCreated";

  const query = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("pieces")
    .orderBy(order, "desc");

  const foundPieceSnapshots = findFromQuery(query, (doc) => {
    const author = doc.get("userId");
    return following.includes(author);
  }, 10, 10, 1000, after);

  const userFollowedPieces = foundPieceSnapshots.map(piece => ({
    ...piece.data(),
    docId: piece.id
  }));

  const lastSnapshot = foundPieceSnapshots[foundPieceSnapshots.length-1];
   
  const piecesWithUserDetails = await Promise.all(
    userFollowedPieces.map(/* ... */)
  );

  return { piecesWithUserDetails, lastSnapshot };
}
```

Comment: What a beautiful elaborate answer. Thank you I'll be sure to try this